# discord.py module not working when I run the code

Tags: discord.py

**The error I get after running my code:**

```py
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\Brandonschoollaptop3\Desktop\bot.3.8 garreled\main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Brandonschoollaptop3\Desktop\bot.3.8 garreled\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    async def subtokb(ctx):
  File "C:\Users\Brandonschoollaptop3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1263, in decorator
    self.add_command(result)
  File "C:\Users\Brandonschoollaptop3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1149, in add_command
    raise CommandRegistrationError(command.name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command subtokb is already an existing command or alias.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.639 seconds
```

Comment: Which code are you running? Which `module` are you talking about? A bit more information would be useful. *The error itself is telling you the solution though... `subtokb` is already a command or alias, you need to rename it*

Answer (score 0):

The error defines itself. There are 2 commands with the name `subtokb`

Comment: This can be posted as a comment, no need for a real "answer" as we still do not know if anything else is not working.